# Build a 2D array representing a 3D plane (storing its Z-values) as defined by 3 points and the desired size of the array

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, memory, plane

#### Short

I need to find an optimized way to build a 2D numpy array representing a 3D plane (namely storing its Z-values) given three points (to mathematically define the plane) and the desired array size.

#### Details

Given three points `p0`, `p1`, `p2`, and a `size` variable:

```py
import numpy as np
import pylab as plt

p0 = [0.2, -0.4, -0.2]
p1 = [-0.6, 0.1, -0.8]
p2 = [-0.1, 0.3, -0.6]
size = (12000, 17000)
```

The following function shows the idea of how to build a plane out of these 3 points:

```py
def plane(p0, p1, p2, size):
    p0 = np.array(p0)
    p1 = np.array(p1)
    p2 = np.array(p2)
    ux, uy, uz = [p1[0] - p0[0], p1[1] - p0[1], p1[2] - p0[2]]
    vx, vy, vz = [p2[0] - p0[0], p2[1] - p0[1], p2[2] - p0[2]]
    uv = [uy * vz - uz * vy,
          uz * vx - ux * vz,
          ux * vy - uy * vx]
    norm = np.array(uv)    
    d = -np.array(p0).dot(norm)    
    xx, yy = np.meshgrid(range(size[1]), range(size[0]))    
    z = np.array((-norm[0] * xx - norm[1] * yy - d) * 1. / norm[2])
    return(z)
```

The resulting `z` looks like this:

[image: resulting image]

This implementation eats my memory in a few seconds:

[image: memory usage]

#### Question

How would you optimize this to achieve the exact same result with the lowest memory usage as possible (being fast is also not optional...)?

Note: `size` may be 10x larger in both dimensions -> which obviously crashes my Python on a mainstream 2016 laptop.

(Using the most common scientific libraries is perfectly fine)

I'm using Python 3.6.9 (default, Jan 26 2021, 15:33:00) [GCC 8.4.0] on Ubuntu linux 18.04.5.

Comment: `12000, 17000` -> 1.5GiB assuming an 8-byte float. 10x larger -> 1500GiB. Are you sure that's sane?

Comment: Don't forget to select the answer. I noticed that you have some questions in the unanswered queue with answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Up to the computation of `d`, your arrays are small. Everything after that is creating a separate 1.5GiB (12k * 17k * 8bytes/float) temp-array for each part of the operation. You can get rid of most of these arrays entirely, and do the rest in-place. For example:

```
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(...)
```

You really don't need the meshgrid: broadcasting on `np.arange(size[0])[:, None]` and `np.arange(size[1])` will make all the arrays you need. That reduces your size from ~3GiB to ~230KiB for that portion of the data:

```
xx = np.arange(size[1], dtype=float)
yy = np.arange(size[0], dtype=float)[:, None]
```

The expression `z = ...` has approximately seven temporary arrays in it, each one 1.5GiB in size:

1. `t1 = -norm[0] * xx`
2. `t2 = norm[1] * yy`
3. `t3 = t1 - t2`
4. `t4 = t3 - d`
5. `t5 = t4 * 1`
6. `t6 = t5 / norm[2]`
7. `t7 = np.array(t6)`

Some of these arrays may be garbage collected during the computation, but they all need to get allocated at some point. You can get rid of all of them using broadcasting and [in-place operators](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/quickstart.html#basic-operations) or the [`out`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/ufuncs.html#optional-keyword-arguments) parameter to the appropriate [`ufunc`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/ufuncs.html)s:

So:

```
d /= norm[2]
norm /= norm[2]
xx *= -norm[0]
yy *= -norm[1]
yy -= d
z = xx + yy
```

Even in the compact part of the code, you are doing a bunch of unnecessary operations. For example, you call `np.array(p0)` twice. Here is a nicer version of your function:

```
def plane2(p0, p1, p2, size):
    u = np.subtract(p1, p0)
    v = np.subtract(p2, p0)
    uxv = np.cross(u, v)
    d = -np.dot(p0, uxv)
    d /= uxv[2]
    uxv /= uxv[2]
    xx = np.arange(size[1], dtype=float)
    xx *= -uxv[0]
    yy = np.arange(size[0], dtype=float)[:, None]
    yy *= -uxv[1]
    yy -= d
    return xx + yy
```

For sizes 10x smaller than you proposed:

```
%timeit plane(p0, p1, p2, size)
70.1 ms ± 329 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit plane2(p0, p1, p2, size)
8.29 ms ± 302 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

When I increase the size to the one in your question, your implementation crashes while mine completes in a reasonable amount of time:

```
%timeit plane(p0, p1, p2, size)
...
MemoryError: Unable to allocate 1.52 GiB for an array with shape (12000, 17000) and data type float64

%timeit plane2(p0, p1, p2, size)
819 ms ± 37.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Depending on how much RAM you have, and what the settings for free memory in the python process are, you may have trouble increasing your array size by 100x to 152GiB, not matter how efficiently you perform your operations.

Comment: nice and thorough soln!

Comment: @anon01. I've made some updates. Glad you like it

Comment: Thank a lot for all the explanations! Do you by chance know if there is a way to use `ufunc` `..=` on numpy's functions such as `np.dot` or `np.cross` e.g.? And is `np.subtract` faster than the simple minus sign `-` operator? (I also need to check that the incoming points are of true `np.array` type (they may be lists in some cases), that's why I was passing them through `np.array()` first. So, is better to test for their type or to blindly cast them to np.arrays, no matter what they are (list or already arrays)?

Comment: @s.k. `np.subtract` will convert its arguments to arrays, which is why I replaced it the way I did. Because of this, it will be a couple of nanoseconds slower than calling `__sub__` on an existing array, but worth the hassle in this case.

Comment: In general, dot and cross don't have in-place operations because they aren't element-wise operations. Also, you're dealing with 9 floats for input and output: that's 72 bytes. Array metadata is probably bigger than that.

Comment: If you *are* going to cast things to an array, use `np.asanyarray` or `np.array(..., copy=False)` to avoid copying the data. Also, you pretty much never need to call `np.array` or similar on the output of numpy functions. The outputs are pretty much always arrays (`np.split` and `np.where` are notable exceptions)

Comment: The general point of my answer is that you don't need to worry about small operations. Even `xx` and `yy` are not that big, and the overhead of just using python will be about as significant as the cost of the operation. You only really need to optimize access to the huge arrays to avoid copies as much as you can.